# incremental array in ruby, 0..40, [10, 20, 30, 40]

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I offset this array so it only outputs every ten numbers?

```
(0...40)
[10,20,30,40]
```

Comment: Why would it not be `[0,10,20,30,40]`?

Comment: Do you want `0` in the array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `step` method for this:

```
10.step(40,10)
```

The first argument is the number you want to count up to, with the second argument being the "steps" that you take to get there.

Comment: Interesting use of step, I didn't realize you could do that.

Comment: But can you have a 0 as the first integer as well?

Answer (score 4):

```
(0..40).step(10) {|num| puts num }  # => 0 10 20 30 40
```

This will take (0..40) and increment by 10 each time.

Comment: Why is everyone getting downvoted? Tommaso and I got 2 downvotes and jer and Ryan both got one.

Comment: Good question, but it's probably not tactical down-voting: I don't think @Ryan would do it, and Tommaso hasn't cast any downvotes yet.

Comment: @Andrew I know it's not tactical downvoting, since I had considered the same things. Ryan got one too. It's just weird that all the answers here got some. I've seen stuff like that and it baffles me.

Comment: +1 This is cool. I didn't know about `Range#step`. It reads well.

Answer (score 1):

```
(0..40).select { |i| i != 0 && i % 10 == 0 }
```

is one way.

Answer (score 0):

or even the more efficient version ;)

> (1..4).collect { |n| n*10 }